# WHERE variable = ( subquery ) in OpenSQL

Tags: subquery, abap, opensql

I'm trying to retrieve rows from a table where a subquery matches an variable. However, it seems as if the WHERE clause only lets me compare fields of the selected tables against a constant, variable or subquery.

I would expect to write something like this:

```
DATA(lv_expected_lines) = 5.
SELECT partner contract_account
INTO TABLE lt_bp_ca
FROM table1 AS tab1
WHERE lv_expected_lines = (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM table2
    WHERE partner          = tab1~partner
    AND   contract_account = tab1~contract_account ).
```

But obviously this select treats my local variable as a field name and it gives me the error "Unknown column name "lv_expected_lines" until runtime, you cannot specify a field list."

But in standard SQL this is perfectly possible:

```
SELECT PARTNER, CONTRACT_ACCOUNT
FROM TABLE1 AS TAB1
WHERE 5 = (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM TABLE2
    WHERE PARTNER          = TAB1.PARTNER
    AND   CONTRACT_ACCOUNT = TAB1.CONTRACT_ACCOUNT );
```

**So how can I replicate this logic in RSQL / Open SQL?**

If there's no way I'll probably just write native SQL and be done with it.

Comment: Nice question. Frankly said I have never seen a query in which the left hand side in WHERE condition would be a constant either in OpenSQL or in standard SQL. I think it is not possible in OpenSQL, however it might be possible to write the query differently and achieve the same result. Using native SQL in ABAP is never a good option. Let me give it some thought...

Answer (score 2):

The program below might lead you to an Open SQL solution. It uses the SAP demo tables to determines the plane types that are used on a specific number of flights.

```
REPORT zgertest_sub_query.

DATA: lt_planetypes TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF s_planetpp.

PARAMETERS: p_numf TYPE i DEFAULT 62.

START-OF-SELECTION.

  SELECT planetype
         INTO TABLE lt_planetypes
         FROM  sflight
       GROUP BY planetype
       HAVING COUNT( * ) EQ p_numf.

  LOOP AT lt_planetypes INTO DATA(planetype).
    WRITE: / planetype.
  ENDLOOP.
```

It only works if you don't need to read fields from TAB1. If you do you will have to gather these with other selects while looping at your results.

Comment: This can work in most cases but not all, +1. I'd considered a solution with `GROUP BY` but the problem is that that doesn't work very well when the scenario includes objects from table A with 0 entries in table B. For instance getting all planetypes with less than 3 planes in SFLIGHT becomes more difficult. In my case I think it would have led to subpar select performance where coding the logic in ABAP would have been quicker.

Answer (score 1):

For those dudes who found this question in 2020 I report that this construction is supported since ABAP 7.50. No workarounds are needed:

```
SELECT kunnr, vkorg
FROM vbak AS v
WHERE 5 = ( SELECT COUNT(*)
              FROM vbap
             WHERE kunnr = v~kunnr
               AND vkorg = v~vkorg )
 INTO TABLE @DATA(customers).
```

This select all customers who made 5 sales orders within some sales organization.

Answer (score -1):

In ABAP there is no way to do the query as in NATIVE SQL. 
I would advice not to use NATIVE SQL, instead give a try to SELECT/ENDSELECT statement.

```
DATA: ls_table1 type table1,
      lt_table1 type table of table1,
      lv_count  type i.

SELECT PARTNER, CONTRACT_ACCOUNT
INTO ls_table1
FROM TABLE1.

      SELECT COUNT(*)
        INTO lv_count
        FROM TABLE2
       WHERE PARTNER          = TAB1.PARTNER
        AND  CONTRACT_ACCOUNT = TAB1.CONTRACT_ACCOUNT.

  CHECK lv_count EQ 5.
  APPEND ls_table1 TO lt_table1.

ENDSELECT
```

Here you append to ls_table1 only those rows where count is equals to 5 in selection of table2.

Hope it helps.